# i am looking for a simple app that will record gps coordinates against photos and videos

Tags: coordinates, software-recommendations

is there a simple app that will allow my Android phone to record not just a location name against photos and videos, but also the gps coordinates?

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is the site for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all android phones will record the GPS coordinates of a picture in the EXIF data, so you should already have that feature.

http://www.digital-photo-secrets.com/tip/1401/how-do-you-find-the-gps-coordinates-of-your-photos/

http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-or-disable-photo-and-video-geo-location-on-Android_id62637

http://www.howtogeek.com/203592/what-is-exif-data-and-how-to-remove-it/